# Meaning of "side"

Tags: meaning

Could anyone help me to understand this sentence?
"Fog can dissipate just as rapidly, depending on what side of the dew point the temperature is on."
The hardest thing for me here is the meaning of "side".

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate your initial research attempts; for example, looking up *[side](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/side_1)* in the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary turns up as the first definition *either of the two halves of a surface, an object or an area that is divided by an imaginary central line.* A dew point is a temperature, and so you can picture a thermometer with values above and below it— upper and lower or right and left.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Above the dew point is one side, below the dew point is the other side.